# What is the right way to ensure the correct version of a gem is required using bundler?

Tags: ruby, bundler

If I understand correctly puting

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
```

at the top of my ruby source file will ensure that subsequent requires will load the versions of the gems specified in the Gemfile located in the same directory, thus allowing me to develop multiple projects which use different versions of the same gem - is this correct? How is this different from using `Bundler.setup()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `require 'bundler/setup'` it loads [this file](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/030a9c592dd706cfe83f24a7ea1b7187d735e8ca/lib/bundler/setup.rb) which calls `Bundler.setup` for you. This means there's no need for you to include that in your own code.

RubyGems is loaded implicitly by Ruby, unless you're using a *really* old version, so `require 'rubygems'` isn't needed.

Comment: I added require 'rubygems' because that was shown in the bundler documentation here: http://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/bundler_setup.html. Do I need to put require 'bundler/setup' at the top of every ruby file?

Comment: `require 'bundler/setup'` - doesn't need to be in every file but you'd want it to load early as part of the start up of your code e.g. Rails apps have it in `config/boot.rb`